# `dotnet` command run from `systemd` script doesn't find AspNetCore 3.0, but works from command line

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, systemd, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a linux ubuntu 16.04 server used to host a bunch of .NET Core sites and applications (it's a staging server), with a bunch of applications using .NET Core 2.0 and 2.1. The server is using nginx with proxying to serve the content through the web.

I've just deployed a ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC website, installing the ASP.NET Core 3.0 runtime as per instructions here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1604.

If I run `dotnet MyApp.dll` directly from the command line, it boots up and runs fine, serves on port 5000 and everything works sweet. However, if I try to start the app using a systemd service, it doesn't work, with errors in the `journalctl` like:

```
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 systemd[1]: Started IBA Showcase Test API.
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]: The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.0.0' was not found.
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:   - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:       /usr/share/dotnet/
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:   - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:       https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:   - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:       https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:   - The following versions are installed:
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:       2.1.13 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Feb 11 13:57:18 ip-172-31-2-223 dotnet[19193]:       2.2.7 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

My .service file in the `/etc/systemd/system` folder is pretty straightforward and looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=IBA Showcase Test API
Wants=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=www-data
Group=www-data
Environment="DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1"
Environment="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging"
Environment="ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000"
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/ibashowcase/api/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet IBA.Showcase.API.dll
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The logs above shows that it didn't find a version of 3.0. Could you please run the command `dotnet --list-runtimes` to make sure the runtime has been installed successfully?

Comment: The LTS version is 3.1, not 3.0. Those instructions install .NET Core 3.1: `sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-3.1`